# Android - Reading and writing to a DropBox DataStore simultaneously

Tags: android, dropbox

My app is getting the data, i.e. heart rate, from an external Bluetooth device and uploading them to a DropBox DataStore. The data is stored in a new table by date, and the user can see a graph view of the previously recorded data.
My problem is that the user can't go through the history and at the same time get the signal from the Bluetooth device. In my app I have 2 main Activities, one is getting the data from the external Bluetooth device and uploading it to the DropBox DataStore, and the other one calls a query method and creates a ListView with the table names, and when the user chooses a table I create a graphview of the data in that table. But in order to do that, I have to stop the `DbxDatastore` object in the first activity and then call the query method, to get the list of available tables, in the second Activity. I tried to create two different `DbxDatastore` objects with the same name, but it doesn't work and the app crashes.

Comment: Why can't you just use the same `DbxDatastore` object in both activities?

Comment: @smarx I tried to do that, but the app crashes, and I can't figure out why. I have extended the Application class, and I am getting all DropBox objects from that Application class.

Comment: What's the error and stack trace when your app crashes?

Comment: @smarx Yes, you were right. I can use the same `DbxDatastore` object, and read and write very easily at the same time. I had made a mistake which took me 2 days to find. But now I have much better debugging skills.